# What kind of system carries both hot and cool water to my condominium?

Tags: hvac

I have an ancient furnace and air conditioner in my condo.  Basically the building supplies water to every unit.  In the winter it is warm water, the summer cool water.  Every condo has a blower unit which sucks are through something that looks like a radiator and out ducts in the condo.

What is this unit called?  I have to replace the blower motor and am not sure how to explain to the furnace company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a four-pipe hydronic system with individual *air handling units* in each dwelling unit -- this is a very common system in larger buildings of all kinds, and works quite smoothly.  Just tell the HVAC folks that the blower in your AHU is shot and they'll know exactly what's up.